# Persist data sent by Intent between Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

So i have **AppCompatActivity** `A`, `B` and `C`. From `A`, i start activity `B`, passing an **Intent** `I0`. In `B`´s `onCreate` i get `I0` and initialize the UI based on that data. Now i open `C` (from `B`). When i press the `app:navigationIcon` back button of the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` from `C`, `B`'s `onCreate` is called again, but now the Intent `I0` does not contain the data from `getStringExtra("data")` anymore.

I have tried to use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` as mentioned elsewhere, but `onRestoreInstanceState` is not called, and the `savedInstanceState` Bundle is `null` in `onCreate`.

So i'm wondering if there is a way to preserve either the UI state of **Activity** `B` (not destroy it?) or the **Intent** `I0`'s extra data?

I've created an [Example](https://github.com/erf/IntentDataPassingTest) on Github

Comment: When starting activity C, don't close(precisely dont call finish()) the activity B, In this way the Activity B will be still there in the backstack, hence it will not be initialized again.

Comment: @nobalG From B, i just call startActivtity with C - how do i not destroy B ?

Comment: `When i press the back button from C, B's onCreate is called again, but now the Intent I0 is null - so initialization fails this time`. this is obviously not true, you will have the same Intent that started activity B for the first time

Comment: @pskink you are correct; the intent is not null, but the call to getStringExtra returns null

Comment: no, it has the same extras as well

Comment: @pskink that is not the case in my case

Comment: so you did something wrong: post your activity `B` and `C` code

Comment: Will try to make a simple example.

Comment: @pskink i have made a test example now, and i found out that if i press the Android back button, then the Activity onCreate is not called, and the ui is intact. If i do however press the navigationIcon in the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, then onCreate is called with the intent extra null.

Comment: @pskink example here: https://github.com/erf/IntentDataPassingTest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103611/discussion-between-erlend-and-pskink).

Comment: tried android:launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pskink for suggesting to set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` on **Activity** `B`. This solved the problem for me in that `B` is not recreated with an invalid **Intent**.